# Docker-engine confilcts with docker.io

Tags: docker, docker-engine

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Docker version: 1.11.2

I have already installed docker 1.11.2 on my Ubuntu and I want to upgrade it to 1.12. All the steps are as follows:

1. I download the deb pkg named `docker-engine_1.12.3-0~xenial_amd64`.
2. Execute command: `dpkg -i docker-engine_1.12.3-0~xenial_amd64` but notes with errors:

   > docker-engine conficts with docker.io.docker.io (version 1.11.2-0ubuntu5~16.04) has already been installed .
3. So I have to remove docker first by using commands as below:

   ```
   service docker stop
   apt-get remove docker
   apt-get remove --auto-remove docker 
   rm -rf /var/lib/docker
   ```
4. Go to step 2, but with the same errors.

So, I hope someone would help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The conflicting packages (which fight over the same binary) are `docker.io` (from the distribution) and `docker-engine` (from Docker itself).

Your command above does `apt-get remove ... docker`.  Which achieve nothing for the aforementioned problem.

I have different machines running 16.04 and some use `docker.io` (easier, no extra repo) whereas others use `docker-engine`.  I am indifferent. Pick on, `docker` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly restart the ubuntu server with linux command(sudo shutdown -r now), and run the command : apt-get -f install(this command is suggested by the error information), then I install the docker-engine by the following site(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04).